# How to change specific attribute in image tag using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to change image attribute from `data-original=""` to `src=""`

Checkout the codes below

```
<img class="lazyjs bbcodeImage" src="//somesite.com/images/sample.gif" data-original="//somesite.com/images/sample.gif" alt="image">
```

in the above code we have 2 attributes 1st `src=""` and 2nd is `data-original=""` so i want to replace `data-original=""` to `src=""`, I have tried using `str_replace` but it doesn't work,

```
$thumb = str_replace(array('data-original=','src='),array('src=','data='),$thumb);
```

how can i do this using PHP?

Comment: Please show a code example.

Comment: str_replace should do it. `str_replace( array( 'src=', 'data-original=', 'data-pl=' ), array( 'data-pl=', 'src=', 'data-original=' ), $string )`

Comment: How do you check results? Do you see generated html?

Comment: if you change `data-original` with `src` then would it be that their will be two `src` now?

Comment: @MujnoiGyulaTamas thanks man it works now i was using wrong attempt

Comment: If you want to remove the data-original so that you'll have only the src than see @Andrius's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have it in a string because you are trying to use PHP.

Here's what you need to do:

```
$content = '<img class="lazyjs bbcodeImage" src="//somesite.com/images/sample.gif" data-original="//somesite.com/images/sample.gif" alt="image">';
$content = preg_replace('/src="(.+?)"/','',$content); // Removes the old src
$content = str_replace('data-original','src',$content); // Renames data-original to src
```